# Fdisk, partition formatted to 'W95 FAT32 (LBA)', not found in Windows 7

Tags: partitioning, windows, fdisk, fat32

I don't know it is some kind of joke, but I made `W95 FAT32 (LBA)` partition with `fdisk`, format with `mkfs.vfat`, but Windows 7 didn't find this partition. How is it possible? Thanks.

```
root@local:~# fdisk -l /dev/sdb | grep sdb2
/dev/sdb2       1048576 242171903 241123328  115G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
root@local:~# df -T | grep sdb2
/dev/sdb2      vfat     120532192 87823104  32709088  73% /media/hosek/usb_data
root@local:~#
```

Comment: Go Windows Disk Management and see if you can assign drive letter to this partition. https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-open-disk-management-2626080